# How to check with a regex if a String contains two letters and a variable amount of digits in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this very specific use case where I want to check if a String contains 2 lower case letters, concatenated by a variable number of digits and a "-abc".

The "-abc" part must not be variable and should always be "-abc". So in the end only the number of digits can be variable.

It can be like this :

> ab123-abc

or like this :

> ab123456-abc

or even like this :

> cd5678901234-abc

I have tried the following but it does not work :

```
if (s.toLowerCase().matches("^([a-z]{2})(?=.*[0-9])-abc")) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close instead of `(?=.*[0-9])` use `\d*` to match zero or more digits or `\d+` to match one or more digits, so you can use this regex `^[a-z]{2}\d*-abc`

```
if(s.toLowerCase().matches("^[a-z]{2}\\d*-abc")){
   return true;
}
```

[**check regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nkKoES/1)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Just checked the regex demo website, very handy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do the `if` statement. Just do:

```
s.toLowerCase().matches("^[a-z]{2}\d+-abc")
```

as it already returns `true`. Notice my answer is different from the one above because it requires a digit between the letters and `-abc`.

Comment: Yeah, the if statement was to mainly to be explicit, in my code the return statement is : return s.toLowerCase().matches("^[a-z]{2}\\d+-abc");

Answer (score 0):

The regex that you want to use is:

```
 /^[a-z]{2}[0-9]+-abc$/i
                ^ 
               "+" means "at least 1"
```

This will match exactly two letters, at least one number, and a trailing `-abc`.

You can also use the *Pattern* class to create a single Regex object. You can then use the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag to ignore case.